# Shouldn't mysql_real_escape_string() leave slashes in Database?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, smarty

Im using smarty and `mysql_real_escape_string()` for user input,
and when I insert some code with `'` or `"` , and lookup in phpmyadmin
it shows without backslashes.

When I get record from DB i doesn't have backslashes also.
But when I just pass escaped string without inserting into the db
it is backslashed.

Shouldn't it add slashes, insert with them and then I would 
strip them when i would output?
Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're missing it - escaping with backslashes is meant to ensure that queries aren't malformed, e.g. something like this will surely break and possibly risk SQL injections:

```
insert into table values ('whatever 'this' is')
```

and nothing will be saved in the table, whereas this:

```
insert into table values ('whatever \'this\' is')
```

will save the value "whatever 'this' is" in the table.